# Image is displayed larger in browsers that it is

Tags: html, image

I'm trying to create a mail signature in html format and paste it to Thunderbird. 
I've noticed when I display it in browser (Chrome, Firefox, IE, any, 100% zoom) - it is larger in size than in Photoshop (100% zoom).

My HTML code (all three samples are displayed in the same size):

> ```
> <html>
>   <body>
>     <img src="test_image.jpg"></img>
>     <br><br>
>     <img src="test_image.jpg" width="400" height="191"></img>
>     <br><br>
>     <img src="test_image.jpg" style="width:400px;height:191px;"></img>
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```

Test image: http://protein.nmr.ru/fish/pics/test_image.jpg

Comparison: http://protein.nmr.ru/fish/pics/comparison.jpg

Signature HTML file: http://protein.nmr.ru/fish/pics/signature.html

What am I doing wrong? I've tried also different dpi settings with the same result.. How to display it as in Photoshop?

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="http://protein.nmr.ru/fish/pics/test_image.jpg" alt="Mountain View">

<img src="http://protein.nmr.ru/fish/pics/test_image.jpg" width="auto" height="auto">

<img src="http://protein.nmr.ru/fish/pics/test_image.jpg" style="width:400px;height:191px;">
```

Using the word `auto` should display the picture with its native resolution, so try using that attribute and see what happens. The funny thing is that I got all three of them to be the same size too. I used the chrome inspect tool to see the dimensions of the picture and it was `400px X 191 px`, which would explain why the second and third elements would show the same thing. I'm guessing that the first element also shows the default resolution of the picture.

Comment: Hi Nathan

Using 'auto' not working for me as well..

All three from your example are displayed larger.

You can right click on image - save it and open then in image viewer and compare to what you see in Chrome.

I used chrome too..